# Install phonegap error in windows

Tags: cordova, npm

I'm trying to install phonegap, but npm is returning the following error::

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm install -g phonegap
```

npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-js/-/cordova-js-3.6.2.t
gz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/properties-parser/-/properties-
parser-0.2.3.tgz

Comment: Sounds like a network problem to me...

Comment: i'm try set proxy:
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080 
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080

Comment: Did you also try adding 'npm config set strict-ssl false' or maybe 'npm config set https-proxy'